# Propensity score matching in r using panel data

Tags: r, panel-data, causality, propensity-scores, matching

I want to conduct PSM using firm panel data in r.

```
matchit(treat ~ leverage + cash + roa + mtb + asset, data=data)
```

This gave me a result of only very similar one without any identifier information.

But I want to obtain a matching result from the same year and the same firm and the same industry with identifier ID. What code should use in R?